# how to remove a property from an array of objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

How to remove a property from an array of objects

need to be removed first _id, usedDays, put two arrays (start and end) into the one and deploy "user" in userId and name.

Have array:

```
[{
    "_id": "someID",
    "user": {
      "_id": "mongoID",
      "name": "Vasya"
    },
    "usedDays": 1,
    "start": "2021-07-02",
    "end": "2021-07-21"
  },
  {
    "_id": "someID",
    "user": {
      "_id": "mongoID",
      "name": "Ivan"
    },
    "usedDays": 5,
    "start": "2021-08-12",
    "end": "2021-08-22"
  }
]
```

Need array:

```
  [{
    "userId": "mongoID",
    "name": "Vasya"
    "partyDate": ["start": "2021-07-02","end": "2021-07-21"]
  },
  {
    "userId": "mongoID",
    "name": "Ivan"
    "partyDate": ["start": "2021-08-12","end": "2021-08-22"]
  }
]
```

Comment: Please post your question at [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/) if it's in russian.

Comment: What have you tried so far? You will need some custom code for this. Please show what you have tried, and which part is not working? Where does "partyDate" come from, it was not in the original data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Array.map is what you are looking for

```
array.map((item) => {
    return ({
        userId: item.user._id, 
        name: item.user.name, 
        partyDate: [{start: item.start, end: item.end}]
    })
})
```